# get view controller stack from storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I try to get view-controllers array of Navigation Controller.It will returns blank array as shown below:

```
   UIStoryboard *mystoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil]; 
UINavigationController *nav1 = [mystoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nav1"];
 NSLog(@"%@",nav1.viewControllers);
```

but this displays empty array even though it has view controller.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the image of your storyboard covering the part where your navigation controller is connected with other view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It would give an empty array. The reason is pretty simple. when you say `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nav1"`, this would instantiate a new `UINavigationController` with identifier `nav1`.

At this point All I understand is you want to get the total number of view controllers from this NavigationController.

You can do this in any viewcontroller that you have pushed over this navigation controller by using this code

`NSArray *VCArray = self.navigationController.viewControllers;`

Hope this solve your problem. However if it doesn't, I cannot help you more without know your implementation and problem to some extend.

Answer (score 0):

Below Code may be helpful to you:

Code is :

```
NSMutableArray *navigationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];
```

This is getting all view controller which is push into stack.